# is it possible to have an OR statement with jquery functions?

Tags: jquery

I have the following bit of code that triggers some ajax events on a form:

```
jQuery('#input1').change(function(){ //bla bla bla });
```

For some reason, if the page refreshes (such as in a failed form submit due to invalidation), this event no longer triggers. Is it possible to fire the `//bla bla bla` part on change OR if the value of #input1 is whatever?

Comment: How is the page being submitted/changed? If the target element (`#input1`) is *reconstructed* (e.g. the existing elements are *replaced*) then you will need to 1) re-add the events 2) use `on` (or equivalent with deferred events) or 3) use `livequery` or similar. (The "no longer triggers" bit is confusing and should be investigated or clarified.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just inside your `$(document).ready()` do a conditional check:

```
if($("#input1").val() == "some value"){
  $("#input1").change();
  // or $("#input1").trigger("change");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

You can put your event here and try